# Catalog Price Rules 'switching off'

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community, catalog-price-rules

Im using Magento ver. 1.9.2.4 CE

I have few different Catalog Price Rules that are applied across customer groups which give 20%, 30%, etc off of products.
The problem I'm having is that the rules, even though they are still in place, seem to 'switch off' within a day or so of having them applied.

As an example, when working correctly the website shows the discount price and 30% off label. Everything is fine through the checkout process.

[image]

When things go 'wrong' after an unknown period of time (usually within 24 hours), the discounted price is shown, but the 30% off label disappears and when added to the cart, the product is listed at it's full price.

[image]

To correct this, I have to go into Promotions > Catalog Price Rules and click 'Apply Rules', which is obviously not great for me having to do this each day. Has anyone come across, or have a solution to my problem please?

Thanks